# how to prevent chrome to use cached copy of html css and js files instead of new build data from server in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, caching

guys, I have a problem with chrome caching in an angular/cli project.I'm using angular 4 and when I make some changes in HTML, CSS or JS files and deploy it on the server my chrome can not show the new changes and when I clear browser cache it shows them.

Comment: I had similar issues when I had a web-worker actived. You can unregister them in Chrome Dev Tools => Application => Service Workers while visiting the app.

Comment: I actually resolve the issue. In the  Nginx config in web server, I just excluded the expiry for index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cache-Control headers. For e.g.

> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate.

References :

[WebPage caching across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/7491048)

[Cache Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/headers/cache-control)

[HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

Answer (score 0):

The minimal configs needed to be set on the response header.

- set "Cache-Control" with value "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
- set "Pragma" with  "no-cache" // HTTP 1.0.
- set "Expires" with "0"

With these values set, most of the browsers should not do caching.

Reference from
[How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue too, my app was on **NGINX**, and I've added a header to NGINX config. file